# Else condition in robot framework not running

Tags: robotframework

I am trying run:

```
Run keyword if ${browser}='chrome'  somekeyword
Else if ${browser}='ff'  somekeyword
```

it's giving me a format error I am running as per doc. can anyone suggest the error?

Comment: Whats the error...?

Comment: Please use markup to show your code exactly as it appears in your file. Is the code on one line or two? Do you ahve two or more spaces before "Else if"?

Comment: thanks space was the issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Run Keyword If  ${browser}=='chrome'  keyword
... ELSE IF  ${browser}=='ff'  keyword
... ELSE  keyword
```

Keep proper space either tab or 2+ spaces as this may also be the reason as suggested by @Bryan Oakley

Hope this helps if not do post the exact keywords you have used with the error...